# Unfolding terms created with `assert` in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, homotopy-type-theory

The proof in question can be found [here](https://x80.org/collacoq/unemuxorof.coq). At the current state, I would like to unfold `eqvid` and `eqvneg` in hypothesis `eqveq`, in order to simplify the projection and obtain a contradictory equality between two different functions. However, these two terms were synthesized as subgoals using the `assert` tactic, and it seems that the current environment bears no memory of the values of the terms. I know that I could write the two terms manually, but that would be quite cumbersome in my opinion. Is there a more elegant way to recover the definitions generated in solving the subgoals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incant:

```
unshelve epose (eqvid := _ : isequiv bool bool).
```

`pose`/`set` are transparent while `assert` is not. The `_` becomes a new existential variable (or unification variable in more standard parlance). A normal `pose` would fail because it can't solve for the variable, but `epose` skips the check. Existential variables aren't usually attacked by tactics directly (they are solved for by unification), so they are automatically shelved, but `unshelve` takes all the evars made by the tactic it controls and turns them into goals.

Replace the asserts with this (you could make a custom notation if you wanted) and

```
apply (f_equal (fun f => f false)) in eqveq.
discriminate.
```

finishes your proof.

Note that the proof state gets rapidly unreadable if you do this. A trick to avoid that is to have

```
Definition hidden {A} {x : A} : A := x.
```

And use

```
unshelve epose (eqvid := hidden : isequiv bool bool).
```

instead. Then the hypotheses will not show the messy term until you reveal it.